# Ошибка при попытке загрузить файл с диска yandex через webdav

Tags: php, webdav, яндекс-диск

Всем привет. Я пытаюсь загрузить большой файл с диска yandex с помощью webdav, но в качестве ответа я получаю следующую ошибку

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24379392 bytes)

Но при попытке загрузить в yandex , логика работает нормально

**Я не хочу делать изменения в моем файле php.ini. Я хочу только улучшить логику**